# React Native minHeight acting like paddingBottom, how is this happening?

Tags: react-native, layout, styles

I have one container that wraps some children. The number of children is dynamic, and when there are none, the parent container is not visible. To address this, I added the `minHeight` value, and perfect, it worked as expected. However, when there are children, this `minHeight` is somehow behaving as `padding-bottom`, for sure.

I know this sounds crazy, and it's been driving me crazy, but I'm sure of it. I know this to be the case because I've reviewed all the styling over and over and when I remove the `minHeight` value when there are two rows or more of children, this effect goes away! However, now I'm back to square one which is the parent is not visible without this `minHeight` when there are no children. So I have no idea how to fix this. I've replicated the situation on [this](https://snack.expo.dev/Uo7p1yAhe) Snack demo, and strangely, it behaves just fine there.  So I have no idea how the heck this is happening, does anyone have any idea what setting might cause `minHeight` to behave like a `padding-bottom`?

With `minHeight`:
[image]

Without `minHeight` (but now I can't see black background when no children are present):
[image]

Comment: Isn't the minHeight just setting the minimum height? If you add more rows of elements, the extra black space should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

you need to know the height for children to order put the correct height for the parent
you can handle height for children in const like this

```js
const HEIGHT_ELEMETE=20
```

then put this var in your style

```js
  parent: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 2,
    minHeight: HEIGHT_ELEMETE,
  },
  element: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    padding: 2,
    margin: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    height:HEIGHT_ELEMETE
  },
```

[expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@yoel301/childwrapstylingexample)